# Euler angle of rotation to Axis-angle?

Tags: c, math, matrix, rotation, trigonometry

I have a CSV file of Pitch X, Yaw Y, and Roll Z values. I want to convert those XYZ values to axis-angle values (XYZ and Theta). I tried to do the following, but the values I got do not seem to be correct after comparing with online converts.

```
void eulerToAxisAngle(double euler[3], double axis_angle[4]) {
    double cy = cos(euler[1] * 0.5);
    double sy = sin(euler[1] * 0.5);
    double cp = cos(euler[0] * 0.5);
    double sp = sin(euler[0] * 0.5);
    double cr = cos(euler[2] * 0.5);
    double sr = sin(euler[2] * 0.5);

    axis_angle[0] = cy * cp * cr + sy * sp * sr;
    axis_angle[1] = cy * cp * sr - sy * sp * cr;
    axis_angle[2] = sy * cp * sr + cy * sp * cr;
    axis_angle[3] = sy * cp * cr - cy * sp * sr;
}

double euler_input[3] = {-6.017, 0.487, -0.412};
double axis_angle_output[4];
eulerToAxisAngle(euler_input, axis_angle_output);
printf("x: %f, y: %f, z: %f, angle: %f\n", axis_angle_output[0], axis_angle_output[1], axis_angle_output[2], axis_angle_output[3]);
```

After doing some research, it seems that my approach is correct I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
If someone could help me or point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Are your angles in degrees?

Comment: @WeatherVane The XYZ values are labeled as (Gyroscope - X Pitch, Y Yaw, Z Roll), so I'm assuming Rads/Sec? Here is an example:

X Pitch: -6.017, Y Yaw: 0.487, Z Roll: -0.412

Comment: Why 'rads/sec' and not just 'rads'? It's not wrong but unsual to specify `-6.017` radians, which is `0.266` radians

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm not sure I understand what you meant. -6.017 is the Pitch value I was given in the sheet. I assumed rads/sec because that is what a gyro reading with be in right?

Comment: Radians are usually expressed in the range ±π. That's why I asked if they are degrees here. A gyro compass usually gives angles, not rate of turn, but it might depend on how sophisticated the sensor is.

Comment: Including the expected correct values of the results of those sample input numbers would be useful.

Comment: @wiswasi "I got do not seem to be correct after comparing with online converts." --> What did you get?  What were the online results? What did you expect?

Comment: @wiswasi  Tip: when debugging problems involving FP, use `"%g"` --> `printf("x: %g, y: %f, z: %g, angle: %g\n", ...`.  It is more informative.

Comment: @wiswasi For debugging, initialize `axis_angle_output[]` to something interesting: `double axis_angle_output[4] = { 1,2,3,4};`.

Comment: In general the unit of gyrosensor output will be `degs/sec`. For instance, `-6.017 degs/sec`
looks like a reasonable value for a motion control. (-6.017 rads/dec should be too much!)
If so, you need to convert degs to rads by multiplying with `π/180`.
Besides the conversion caclulations will be:
`x = sy * sp * cr + cy * cp * sr`
`y = sy * cp * cr + cy * sp * sr`
`z = cy * sp * cr - sy * cp * sr`
and
`angle = 2 * acos(cy * cp * cr - sy * sp * sr)`.

Comment: Hey guys, I found out the these values `{-6.017, 0.487, -0.412}` are in degrees/sec.
So now I need to convert from deg/sec to Axis-Angle (x, y, z, and theta)